# Any mechanism in Java 8/NIO for replacing the lines of a big file without loading it in memory?

Tags: java, stream, nio

I am basically looking for a solution that allows me to stream the lines and replace them IN THE SAME FILE, a la Files.lines

Comment: To do what you suggest your file would need to be formatted in a way which allows this sort of change. i.e. a data structure. A flat text file needs to be re-written from the point you change it (unless you don't change the length)

Comment: Would it be an option to use shell commands in a Process? Like on Linux you could issue some sort of `sed` command ... I know this would bring drawbacks like OS-Dependency with it but if it is your only chance ...

Comment: @Fildor `sed` doesn't operate *in situ*.

Comment: @EJP - ah, right ...

Answer (score 2):

> Any mechanism in Java 8/NIO for replacing the lines of a big file without loading it in memory?

Basically, no.

Any change to a file that involves changing the number of bytes between offets A and B can only be done by rewriting the file, or creating a new one.  In either case, everything after B has to be loaded / read into memory.

This is not a Java-specific restriction.  It is a consequence of the way that modern operating systems represent files, and the low-level (ie.e. syscall) APIs that they provide to applications.

---

In the specific case where you replace one line (or sequence of lines) with a line (or sequence of lines) of exactly the same length, then you can do the replacement using either RandomAccessFile, or by mapping the file into memory.  Note that the latter approach won't cause the entire file to be read into memory.

---

It is also possible to replace or delete lines while updating the file "in place" (changing the file length ...).   See @Sergio Montoro's answer for an example.  However, with an in place update, there is a risk that the file will be corrupted if the application is interrupted.  And this does involve reading and rewriting all bytes in the file after the insertion / deletion point.  And that entails loading them into memory.

Answer (score 1):

There was a mechanism in Java 1: `RandomAccessFile`; but any such in-place mechanism requires that you know the start offset of the line, and that the new line is the same length as the old one.

Otherwise you have to copy the file up to that line, substitute the new line in the output, and then continue the copy.

You certainly don't have to load the entire file into memory.

Comment: That mechanism still exists. Though NIO offers memory mapping, which might have a higher performance for that use case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

A FileChannel allows random read/write to any position of a file. Therefore, if you have a read ahead buffer which is long enough you can replace lines even if the new line is longer than the former one.

The following example is a toy implementation which makes two assumptions: 1st) the input file is ISO-8859-1 Unix LF encoded and 2nd) each new line is never going to be longer than the next line (one line read ahead buffer).

Unless you definitely cannot create a temporary file, you should benchmark this approach against the more natural stream in -> stream out, because I do not know what performance may a spinning drive provide you for an algorithm that constantly moves forward and backward in a file.

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ReplaceInFile {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Path file = Paths.get(args[0]);
        ByteBuffer writeBuffer;
        long readPos = 0l;
        long writePos;
        String line_m;
        String line_n;
        String line_t;
        FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(file, READ, WRITE);
        channel.position(0);
        writePos = readPos;
        line_m = readLine(channel);
        do {
            readPos += line_m.length() + 1;
            channel.position(readPos);
            line_n = readLine(channel);
            line_t = transformLine(line_m)+"\n";
            writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(line_t.length()+1);
            writeBuffer.put(line_t.getBytes("ISO8859_1"));
            System.out.print("replaced line "+line_m+" with "+line_t);          
            channel.position(writePos);
            writeBuffer.rewind();
            while (writeBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                channel.write(writeBuffer);
            }
            writePos += line_t.length();
            line_m = line_n;
            assert writePos > readPos;
        } while (line_m.length() > 0);
        channel.close();
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

    public static String transformLine(String input) throws IOException {
        return input.replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;");
    }

    public static String readLine(FileChannel channel) throws IOException {
        ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
        StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
        do {
            int read = channel.read(readBuffer);
            if (read<1) break;
            readBuffer.rewind();
            char c = (char) readBuffer.get();
            readBuffer.rewind();
            if (c=='\n') break;
            line.append(c);
        } while (true);
        return line.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: This works if the modified string has the same length of the source string, otherwise if the target string is shorter than the source string, you will keep traces of the original lines in your file. If you add a channel.truncate(writePos-1); at the end it works perfectly.